# .dropbox files, can they be deleted?

Tags: file-management, dropbox

I use Dropbox on my Windows 7, OS X and on my mobile phone. Sometimes I see a file called `.dropbox` in my dropbox folders, can those files be deleted?

Comment: look this one in their forum. not yet answered. [https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=49881](https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=49881)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Dropbox uses the .dropbox files as a tool to track the identity of a
>   shared folder. When a shared folder is moved, and IF you haven't
>   deleted the .dropbox file, dropbox recognizes the shared folder still,
>   and it keeps it's shared property. If you have deleted the .dropbox
>   files, then if you move the shared folder you will leave the shared
>   folder.

So, if you want to keep it shared, keep it - if you don't, you can remove it.

Note that moving a shared folder implies that you move it within dropbox structure.

Also, they say that in previous version of dropbox there was a bug that .dropbox files existed in all directories, but that should've been fixed years ago.

Sources:

- https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=3842
- https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=18965

Comment: To a user suggesting this answer is a copy of https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=49881 answer - compare the dates. Also, in that thread it is clearly indicated that it is a copy of this answer, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

I have this .dropbox files too, I just delete them and never notice them again... 
Most of the time, the files will just normally sync with your other device.